Saving Captured image through intent or from gallery into room Database
I have been trying to save Captured image into Room Database and upload it to server later with other details. The image Capturing code is as below
val activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    val uri: Uri? = if (data?.data != null){ data.data }else{ billUri }
                    if (uri != null) {

                        chequeBitmap = uriToBitmap(this, uri)

                        binding.chequeimage.setImageBitmap(chequeBitmap)
                        binding.addimage.visibility = View.GONE

                        binding.chequeimage.setOnClickListener {
                            // Clear the image and show the add image button
                            binding.chequeimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_upload)
                            binding.addimage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

        }

        binding.addimage.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE, "Gallery")
            
            val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm_ss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir("DO_NOT_DELETE")
            val photoFile: File? = File.createTempFile(
                "Bill_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
            )
            photoFile?.let { file ->
                val billURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.provider", file)
                billUri = billURI
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, billURI)
            }

when i uploads it into database it uploads it successfully but due to high size of row in sqlite database it is unreadable by application. And then application crashes permently until database is deleated.
I am trying to save Image as ByteArray into Room Database
data class DepositData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    var bill: String,
    val payimage: ByteArray
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as DepositData

        return payimage.contentEquals(other.payimage)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return payimage.contentHashCode()

I want that the image size should be reduced to 1.5 MB(max) and save into room Database without spoiling image Quality or its Clarity. Previously i used to capture images as thumbnail but it won't useful for clear images. The image is blur when loaded. I Don't want to save image URI into room as that can be deleted by the user and app could crash due to that.
To upload it into database i use below code:
binding.save.setOnClickListener {
    val payImage: ByteArray = bitmapToByteArray(chequeBitmap)!!

    val data = DepositData(0, bill = bill, payimage = payImage)
    collectionViewModel.insertRecord(data)
}


"I want that the image size should be reduced to 1.5 MB(max)... without spoiling image Quality or its Clarity" -- that is not necessarily possible. "I Don't want to save image URI into room as that can be deleted by the user and app could crash due to that" -- have you considered saving a copy of the image as an app-local file (e.g., getCacheDir() on Context) with a unique filename, then putting the filename in Room? Android's SQLite support does not work well with large binary data.


when i uploads it into database it uploads it successfully but due to high size of row in sqlite database it is unreadable by application

This is not necessarily true as the limitations of the underlying CursorWindow can be circumvented.

The SQLite API which Room utilises extract data into a Cursor, which utilises buffering of rows of data. This buffer is a CursorWindow which MUST be able to buffer at least one full row. If the size of a row exceeds the buffer size then an exception occurs.

As such reducing the size of an extracted row can overcome the limitation.
The reduction could be made either by extracting the data from the too larg BLOB in manageable amounts to then be combined.

From the demo below, which inserts an image that is too large:-

Error reading Sqlite table "AltImage": Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1


Then part of the image can be extracted e.g. by:-



A recursive CTE could be utilised to extract all the parts which could then drive a function to combine all the parts as one.



The alternative would be to store the data in manageable chunks/blocks to then be combined. This is probably the simpler method and more akin to Room's object orientated approach as you could have a parent Image object along with the underlying chunk objects.
Saying that the suggested approach, in regard to images/media is to store a means of then extracting the media, which could well be within the App's data.
Demo
The following is a simple demo that has a largish image (3MB) in the assets folder, which is then stored in the database via both methodologies.

Methodology 1, is based upon a single AltImage @Entity annotated object (SQLite table), which has an id and image field (BLOB)
Methodology 2, is to split the data into chunks, there are 2 @Entity annotated objects (SQLite tables);

the ImageParent which contains all information bar the actual ByteStream/ByteArray/BLOB, and,
the DataChunk that has a reference/map/relationship to it's parent object/table.



So the 3 @Entity annotated objects for BOTH methodologies are:-
@Entity
data class AltImage(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val image: ByteArray
)

@Entity
data class ImageParent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val timestamp: Long=System.currentTimeMillis(),
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val imageName: String
)
@Entity
data class DataChunk(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val mapTo_ImageParent: Long,
    val chunk: ByteArray
)

To facilitate the 2nd (chunk) methodology there is also a FullImage object that facilitates extraction of the related data using the @Embedded and @Relation annotation. The class also has a couple of functions to facilitate handling the chunks (splitting and combining):-
data class FullImage(
    @Embedded
    val imageParent: ImageParent,
    @Relation(
        entity = DataChunk::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "mapTo_ImageParent"
    )
    val dataChunkList: List<DataChunk>
) {
    companion object {
        fun getArrayOfChunks(fullImage: ByteArray): ArrayList<ByteArray> {
            val rv: ArrayList<ByteArray> = ArrayList()
            var offset=0
            while(offset < fullImage.size) {
                Log.d("APPINFO","getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is ${offset} FullImageSize = ${fullImage.size}")
                if (fullImage.size - (offset + CHUNK_SIZE) >0) {
                    rv.add(fullImage.copyOfRange(offset, offset + CHUNK_SIZE))
                } else {
                    rv.add(fullImage.copyOfRange(offset,offset + (fullImage.size-offset)))
                }
                offset+= CHUNK_SIZE
            }
            return rv
        }
    }
    fun getCombinedChunks(): ByteArray {
        val rv: ArrayList<Byte> = ArrayList()
        for (c in dataChunkList) {
            for (b in c.chunk)
                rv.add(b)
        }
        return rv.toByteArray()
    }
}

As for accessing the database the single @Dao annotated AllDAOs interface is:-
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(imageParent: ImageParent): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(dataChunk: DataChunk): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(altImage: AltImage)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM imageparent")
    fun getAllFullImages(): List<FullImage>
}

To put it all together then an @Database annotated class:-
@Database(entities = [ImageParent::class,DataChunk::class,AltImage::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the DEMO */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}

To actually utilise above then activity code:-
const val CHUNK_SIZE=1024 * 4

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val theImage = this.assets.open("theimage.JPG").readBytes()
        Log.d("APPINFO","Image length=${theImage.size}")
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()
        val altImageId = dao.insert(AltImage(null,theImage.copyOf()))
        val ipId = ImageParent(id =dao.insert(ImageParent(imageName = "TheImage")), imageName = "TheImage")
        for(dc in FullImage.getArrayOfChunks(theImage)) {
            dao.insert(DataChunk(null, mapTo_ImageParent = ipId.id!!,dc))
        }

        val extracted = dao.getAllFullImages()
        for (e in extracted) {
            Log.d("APPINFO"," Image has ${e.dataChunkList.size} chunks of (${CHUNK_SIZE}) (note last chuck may be smaller) bytearray size is ${e.getCombinedChunks().size}")
        }
    }
}

When the above is run (from a fresh install) the following results are shown in the log:-
2024-05-07 10:28:01.983 D/APPINFO: Image length=3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.137 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 0 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 4096 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 8192 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 12288 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 16384 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 20480 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 24576 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 28672 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.153 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 32768 FullImageSize = 3422566
....
2024-05-07 10:28:02.218 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 3403776 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.218 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 3407872 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.218 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 3411968 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.218 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 3416064 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:02.218 D/APPINFO: getArrayOfChunks Loop, Offset is 3420160 FullImageSize = 3422566
2024-05-07 10:28:03.997 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 4096 bytes, free space 3884 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2024-05-07 10:28:04.538 D/APPINFO:  Image has 836 chunks of (4096) (note last chunk may be smaller) bytearray size is 3422566


As can be seen the length of the image extracted 3422566 matches the length of the image itself.
The trapped/caught Window full, I believe, is due to initial establishment of the number of rows that can be held by the CursorWindow.

In addition to the previously shown Window Full when trying to access the AltImage table. App Inspection also shows:-


i.e. the single ImageParent row that was inserted

and:-



Through to :-



i.e. there are 836 4K blocks and thus up to 3,424,256 bytes, the last being 2046 bytes according to:-



2nd Demo (Recursive Query to break an image into parts that can be retrieved)
First the simple part, building an AltImage with the large ByteArray (image) but extracted via multiple parts (they themselves ByteArrays):-
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun buildAltImage(id: Long): AltImage {
    val image = arrayListOf<Byte>()
    for (c in getImageChunksAsChunkedDataList(CHUNK_SIZE,id)) {
        image.addAll(c.toTypedArray())
    }
    return AltImage(id,image.toByteArray())
}


@Transaction and @Query are not required but doesn't hurt to have them in (a habit)

Obviously, the crux is the getImageChunksAsChunkedDataList function. That is:-
@Query("/* The Recursive Query being demonstrated */" +
        "WITH " +
        "/* Single value for the chunksize stored in a CTE so it can be passed just the once as a bound parameter */" +
        "    cte_chunksize AS (SELECT :chunkSize /*<<<<<<BOUND*/), " +
        "    /* Single value for the image in a CTE so the selection criteria (id) can be passed just the once as a bound parameter */" +
        "    cte_baseimage AS (SELECT image FROM altimage WHERE id=:id /*<<<<<BOUND*/)," +
        "    /* Recursively grab chunks of the image */" +
        "    cte_chunked AS (" +
        "        SELECT " +
        "            1 AS counter," +
        "            substr((SELECT image FROM cte_baseimage),1,(SELECT * FROM cte_chunksize)) AS current_chunk, " +
        "            substr((SELECT image FROM cte_baseimage),(SELECT * FROM cte_chunksize)+1) AS remaining_data " +
        "        UNION ALL SELECT  " +
        "            counter + 1, " +
        "            substr(remaining_data,1,(SELECT * FROM cte_chunksize)), " +
        "            substr(remaining_data,(SELECT * FROM cte_chunksize)+1) " +
        "        FROM cte_chunked " +
        "        WHERE length(remaining_data) > 0 " +
        "        LIMIT 2000 " +
        ") " +
        "SELECT current_chunk FROM cte_chunked ORDER BY counter ASC;"
)
fun getImageChunksAsChunkedDataList(chunkSize: Int, id: Long): List<ByteArray>

This utilises CTEs (Common Table Expressions which are temporary tables that exist for the duration of the statement being executed).

The first CTE cte_chunksize is a single row table(CTE) that has the value of the chunksize to be used which has been passed to the function.

The second CTE cte_baseimage is the image (the excessively size BLOB that the Android Cursor cannot handle). However, it is SQLite that handles it.

The third CTE cte_chunked recursively selects a chunk of the data and at the same time selects the remaining data. The recursion (the UNION ALL with itself) then uses the previous existing row as the basis of a new row until a WHERE/LIMIT clause is met thus stopping the recursion (not as a just in case both have been used, however the WHERE clause is the one that should be met BUT the LIMIT clause may result in not all data being extracted if the image exceeds nearly 8Mb for a value of 2000).

it should be noted that this method, as it is, is very resource hungry and thus takes a considerable amount of time.

Note that only very basic testing has been undertaken as the primary object was to demonstrate the principle


Amending the Activity code to include:-
    val extractedAltImage = dao.buildAltImage(altImageId)
    Log.d("APPINFO","Extracted ID is ${extractedAltImage.id} Size of Image is ${extractedAltImage.image.size}")

Results in the log including:-
2024-05-08 11:28:33.880 D/APPINFO:  Image has 836 chunks of (4096) (note last chunk may be smaller) bytearray size is 3422566
2024-05-08 11:28:36.665 D/APPINFO: Extracted ID is 1 Size of Imnage is 3422566


The first line is from the previous code, included as it took nearly 3 seconds just to extract the image (ByteArray).

The full log between the two methods should perhaps be considered:-
2024-05-08 11:28:33.294 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 4096 bytes, free space 3884 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2024-05-08 11:28:33.880 D/APPINFO:  Image has 836 chunks of (4096) (note last chunk may be smaller) bytearray size is 3422566
2024-05-08 11:28:35.082 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 4096 bytes, free space 3728 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2024-05-08 11:28:36.665 D/APPINFO: Extracted ID is 1 Size of Imnage is 3422566
2024-05-08 11:28:36.690 D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2024-05-08 11:28:36.699 I/Choreographer: Skipped 341 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

